# Strange git behaviour with git-bash on windows

Tags: git, http, authentication

I am using this `git` version:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.32.0.windows.2
```

I have cloned a repo with `http`, with credentials. I am myself hosting the repo with `gogs`. Everything is working fine.

Suddently, `git fetch / git pull / git fetch` stops working, after days of using it without issues. I start getting authentication problems, intermittently. After much debugging, I setup a `mitm` reverse proxy. I then realize that *sometimes* git is not sending `Authorization` headers:

```
Authorization: Basic something-something-something
```

This happens even if I use the (insecure) configuration option where I add `user:password` in the `remote` url.

In the normal case, with working clients (`git version 2.25.1`, on `Ubuntu`), I see the following requests / response flow:

```
GET -> 401 unauthorized
GET -> 200 OK
```

The first request I assume is used by git to realize that authorization is needed, and `git` obliges and sends a second request with authorization headers.

But the faulty clients (`git version 2.32.0.windows.2` on `Windows 10`) do not do this. They simply do:

```
GET -> 401 unauthorized
```

And do not send a second request. This does not happen always: intermittently, they revert to the good flow and send a second request, so that the operation succeeds.

I am out of ideas.